# Yii2: Login with pretty URL doesnot apply layout to dashboard

Tags: php, url-rewriting, yii2

I am doing login signup & password reset in single view with three different models for that page in controller's login action. My code is

```
    'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
```

I have login signup & password reset in single view with fade in & fade out effect. When i does login it redirects me to dashboard where the layout main must be applied but no layout is getting applied there.

[image]

Comment: can you be more specific when you're talking about "problems"? what do you mean by "no layout is getting applied"?

Comment: in my yii2 layouts i have created two layouts one is main.php and another is index.php. index.php i am applying at the time of login & when login is successful then dashboard appears where i am applying main.php. thing is when i apply main layout the css is not displayed the content in required form in the edit i am adding screenshot see this...

Comment: the screenshot would do not much help, probably sharing the markup you're receiving as output in the dashboard, the content of the `main.php` layout and the one of `dashboard.php` could probably help solve the problem. Together with that, if you open the network inspector, do you see specific files giving you a 404 or similar errors?

Comment: @The Peach i got where the problem is...w.r.t that i have edited my question. when i tries to login with pretty url i am getting this problem but when i try login without pretty url i am not facing that problem

Comment: the login code doesnot have any issue

Comment: This looks like a problem of paths of the attached styles. Please can you check what are the errors that you get in the network panel? Also paste the relevant code that deals with the CSS in the template/view.

Comment: also comparing the generated path for the stylesheet with and without pretty urls could be useful.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68486/discussion-between-the-peach-and-shaggie).

Comment: yes, yes i got the problem i opened this with firefox developer edition browser, there it shows me that the required javascript & css are not loading.....but this is not happening when i login with ?r=site/login???